# grep "string from file" in subdirectories then copy the entire "folder"

Tags: grep

I am trying to:

1. Find a string "required accuracy" in all files(file name: OUTCAR.txt) in all my subdirectories(approximately 50 folders).
2. Copy only the folders which have files with the searched-for the string to another location

My solution at this time:

```
1. grep -r "required accuracy"
```

I would like to search only in files named OUTCAR though. Otherwise, I have two files from one folder on my list.

```
2. grep -r "required accuracy" OUTCAR -exec scp -r {} ./final location
```

I have no idea at all how to extract the folder list from the list of files that I found with the grep command. Maybe it is possible to use the find command for strings in files?

Comment: How many level of directories do u have and will the file is available only at the end of the tree?

Comment: I basically have one folder "rel1" then in this folder I have 50 folders ( folders with names 1 to 50) with no subdirectories. In each of these folders 1 to 50 there is one OUTCAR.txt. In these OUTCAR.txt the string I am looking for is sometimes there and sometimes not.
I want to copy all the folders which contain the files with the the string I am looking for to another folder "rel1_fin".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 grep -lr 'required accuracy' rel1 | sed 's#/OUTCAR.txt##g' | xargs -I {} mv {} rel1_fin
```

- `-l` Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match

Comment: Thank you! This code works :.).

Answer (score 1):

If your `find` has `-execdir` available:

```bsh
find . -type f -name "OUTCAR.txt" \
-exec grep -q "required accuracy" {} \;
-execdir scp -r ./ "/path/to/final location" \;
```

- find all files (`-type f`) with `-name OUTCAR.txt`.
- `grep` for "required accuracy" in that file,
- If `grep` is successful, run `scp` ... from the directory, that the file is in using `-execdir`.

Note, that `/path/to/final/location` should be an absolute path, or you may use `$PWD/relative/path/from/where/find/is/executed`.

Comment: `-execdir` is a non-standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help :

```
grep -Rl "required accuracy"  ./Source-dir/* | grep OUTCAR | xargs -I[] bash -c 'val="[]";scp -r ${val%/*} user@doman:/destination-direcory'
```